# symfony - composer too old

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, composer-php

I have a problem while I tried to start symfony, the error is:

```
composer require server --dev
Some Symfony Flex features may not work as expected: your version of Composer is too old
Please upgrade using https://getcomposer.org/
```

I tried to update composer, but I can't find the way to do it, in composer documentation [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/) I followed the steps but:

```
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '52cb7bbbaee720471e3b34c8ae6db53a38f0b759c06078a80080db739e4dcab6') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
Installer corrupt
```

So, I'm in a loop of errors, what can I do?

(I'm working in ubuntu)

Of course I tried:

```
composer self-update


  [InvalidArgumentException]             
  Command "self-update" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 1):

The command `self-update` i  only available when you install composer as a phar, not as a dependency in the global project or via apt.

So you need to uninstall `composer` and reinstall it with phar and after you can use self-update

[Documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/)

Comment: Another way would be to update the ubuntu package through `apt-get install composer`

Comment: Updating with apt-get doesn't work. And I don't know how to install composer as a phar. Can you extend your answer please